# Set up Ktor authenticated shutdown route

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'd like to add a shutdown route to my Ktor server but I need it to require authentication.

I'm trying to put the shutdown url in my authenticated routes like so:

```
// application.conf
ktor {
    deployment {
        port = 8080
        host = 127.0.0.1
        shutdown.url = "/shutdown"
    }
}
```

```
// Application.kt
routing {
    root()
    
    authenticate("authenticated-routes") {
        test1()
        test2()
        shutdown()
    }
}

// Routes.kt
fun Route.shutdown() {
    get("/shutdown") {
        // shutting down
    }
}
```

But somehow the shutdown route does not require authentication for shutting down the server (something to do with the config overriding the route defined in `Routes.kt`?)

The docs unfortunately do not give any hints as to how to make the shutdown route authenticated. Any ideas on how I could make sure not just anyone can call the shutdown route and shutdown my server?

Comment: How do you define `"authenticated-routes"`? It should be inside `install(Authentication)`

Comment: Yes absolutely. I was trying to keep the code in this example minimal, but my `install(Authentication)` block is there and well defined. Do you think I should edit the question to add it for completeness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ShutDownUrl` plugin has nothing with `Routing` that's why you can't integrate it with the `Authentication` plugin. To solve your problem you can manually make an instance of `ShutDownUrl` class and execute the `doShutdown` method in a route that may require authentication. Here is an example:

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.auth.*
import io.ktor.response.*
import io.ktor.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*

fun main() {
    val shutdown = ShutDownUrl("") { 1 }

    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 3333) {
        install(Authentication) {
            basic {
                realm = "Access for shutting the server down"
                validate { credentials ->
                    if (credentials.name == "jetbrains" && credentials.password == "foobar") {
                        UserIdPrincipal(credentials.name)
                    } else {
                        null
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        routing {
            get("/") {
                call.respondText { "hello" }
            }

            authenticate {
                get("/shutdown") {
                    shutdown.doShutdown(call)
                }
            }
        }
    }.start()
}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you very much. But it's unclear to me how the empty string in the `ShutDownUrl("")` and the proper url in the `get("/shutdown")` interact.

Comment: The URI in the `ShutDownUrl` constructor is used only when you install the `ShutDownUrl` plugin. This plugin intercepts `ApplicationCallPipeline` and shuts the server down if the requested URI matches provided one. In my sample, I don't install the plugin but call the `doShutdown` method manually in the route. In other words, I use routing to determine when to shut the server down instead of relying on default plugin behavior.